# I have an issue with shadow opacity on android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, expo, dropshadow

- On design file
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5n0m.png)
- On device
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1u5q.png)

It not match with design. My code at here
https://snack.expo.dev/@phuongit0301/card

Please suggest for me solution?

Answer (score 1):

There's no `shadowOpacity` in Android. It only works in iOS.
Check here for [reference](https://reactnative.dev/docs/shadow-props).

The alternative is to use `elevation` property for Android

Comment: I have use elevation property but not work, My code in link 
[link](https://snack.expo.dev/@phuongit0301/card)
Could you take a look?

Comment: @phuong, I checked it, but I have no idea how to implement your design with what elevation can do.